# Disable an input with javascript. Checking the code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a client side in javascript and html. I have a problem. I want to check if password and repeat password are the same. In that case I want to disable an input. I saw some codes around but I don't understand why it doesn't work. Can you help me?
Here is my HTML:

```
<input class="form-control form-stacked last" name="repeatPassword" id="repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="password">
<input class="btn btn-beats btn-block btn-stacked" value="Sign up" onkeydown="enable()" id = "btnPlaceOrder" type="submit">
<input class="form-control form-stacked" name="password" id = "password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="true">
```

And then here is my javascript function:

```
var password = document.getElementById("password");
var repeat = document.getElementById("repeat");
   function enable(){
      if (password.value() == repeat.value()){
         document.getElementById("btnPlaceOrder").disabled = false;
      } else{
         document.getElementById("btnPlaceOrder").disabled = true;
      }
}
```

Just to be precise, I did the import of the javascript in my HTML

Comment: `value` is a property, not a method, so `if(password.value == repeat.value)`

Comment: ok. A point more @pawelbut it still does not work

Comment: What does it means @dystroy?

Comment: Also, when things don't work **always check your browser's console**. In most cases there will be be an error message being logged.

Comment: @pp94 probably the `onkeydown` listener which responds to the keyboard, not the mouse.

Comment: Yes I check the console of chrome (the browser I use) but there are no errors, otherwise I will not put the question

Comment: But I used the enter of the keyboard to check it @pawel

Comment: @pp94 Sorry. Lack of coffee. Forget my stupid comment.

Comment: thanks @Juhana for explain it for me ;)

Comment: @pp94 you should probably add the listener to both fields, i.e. `<input id="password" onkeyup="enable()" />` and the same for repeat password field. Then it will enable/disable as the user types the passwords.

Comment: don't worry @dystroy. It happens :)

Comment: where is id password.

Comment: sorry @pawel but the enable should disable only the Submit "button". Basically the idea is "When the password and the repeat password are different, you cannot press the "button" Submit so you cannot be redirect"

Comment: @suchit sorry. I did an edit and I add the password input

Comment: @pp94 yeah I know, see my answer and linked fiddle.

Comment: why did you use `onkeydown="enable()"` for the `input type="submit"` which is a `button`

Comment: can u  add an onkeyup function to your confirm password field. and n this way when you will tab out of the field you will know if the password is same or not. if they are diffreent then u can disable your submit button

Comment: Thanks to everyone, @pawel gives me the right answer. Thanks for the helping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:
Add listeners to the password inputs, so the submit button fill change its state as the user types.

```
<input id="password" type="password" onkeyup="enable()">
<input id="repeat" type="password" onkeyup="enable()">
<input value="Sign up"  id="btnPlaceOrder" type="submit">
```

JS

```
function enable(){
    // the comparison returns true or false so no need for if/else
    document.getElementById("btnPlaceOrder").disabled = password.value !== repeat.value;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/40vvL1em/

Comment: Amazing. Thanks man (sorry for the amount of functions I have for password and repeat)

Comment: sorry but I have to wait 2 minutes (don't know why) to confirm that your answer is the right one...

Answer (score 1):

Well simply call your function in the `onkeyup()` event of your repeat input.

```
<input class="form-control form-stacked last" name="repeatPassword" id="repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="password" onkeyup="enable()">
```

And here's the JS function:

```
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var repeat = document.getElementById("repeat").value;
function enable(){
if (password === repeat){
  document.getElementById("btnPlaceOrder").disabled = false;
} 
else{
  document.getElementById("btnPlaceOrder").disabled = true;
}
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Ok, his JS  approach is better but I think that you don't have to call `enable()`in the password input keyup event?

Comment: absolutely I didn't want to say that your question is not better. I will check your solution

Comment: Also your solution was right. Thanks @chsdk I want to give the green arrow (sorry I have no idea how to call it in english) to both of you );

Comment: No, @pawel's answer is the most efficient but I just said that pratically there's no need to put the keyup event in the first password input